# Is Neil's Dad Kevin from the TV Show "Inbetweeners" Gay or not?

Tags: character, the-inbetweeners

In the TV Show *The Inbetweeners*, there is a recurring theme as to whether or not Neil's Dad Kevin is actually gay but it's never revealed whether he is gay or not. Just out of curiosity, is he actually gay?

Answer (score 1):

## Supposedly but not definitely.

As long as he doesn't admit it himself (which he didn't yet) we can't be fully sure but all the hints given are he is. There is a trope for this type of character, [Ambiguously Gay](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AmbiguouslyGay).

And even if he is gay he seems to be closed one.